# Blazor Create the component like Facebook Notification or StackOverflow Notification

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, blazor, popup

In blazor NET 8 I would like to implement the "popup" box that appear when clicking in desktop Facebook Notification or the same as in StackOverflow.
I tried using modal but it prevents clicks anywhere else, it hides the rest of the website.
I  just want a window as in StackOverflow notifications.
At least the big steps.

In blazor I have something like :

```
@if (ShowNotificationPopup)
{
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show" @onclick="ToggleNotificationPopup"></div>
    <div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
        <NotificationPopup OnClose="ToggleNotificationPopup" />
    </div>
}
```

With a Razor component like :

```
    <h3>NotificationPopup</h3>

<!-- NotificationPopup.razor -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" id="notificationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notificationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="notificationModalLabel">Notifications</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Your notification content here -->
                <p>Notification 1</p>
                <p>Notification 2</p>
                <!-- Replace with actual notification content -->
            </div>
            <!-- Add footer or additional content if needed -->
            <button @onclick="ClosePopup">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnClose { get; set; }

    private async Task ClosePopup()
    {
        await OnClose.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the Bootstrap classes that are causing the problem. If you go to the Bootstrap docs page and open the dev tools then open one of their modal examples, you'll see it toggles in the `show` class on one of the `element`s.  That's what you need to do is add and remove that class to show/hide the modal.

Comment: The html `<dialog>` has two modes one is to simply place `open` as attribute and the other you use JS to open the dialog. Both have different use cases. The first behaves like a popup the second a modal dialog. The rest is just css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog
I think if your looking for something pre developed your looking for "Toast" popups. Bootstrap needs js enabled for Toast messages. As @MikeT pointed out the JS is just manipulating classes which Blazor can do itself.

Comment: @BrianParker Ok, just reread your Q. If you look at the code you're using, you're using a [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo).  That's not what you want for a notification service. Neither is the `<dialog>` element.  You'll either need to build your own component or check around some of the third party component libraries to see what they offer. I'll post the code for how I solved the issue.

Comment: The Modal wasn't the solution, I've posted the answer I found myself and was looking for :) thanks

Comment: @MikeT I've posted the answer II've done and was looking for . Thanks .

Comment: Oops, I just posted my answer too, lol. You might want to look at it, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @MikeT I'll test your code later. Thanks and Happy New Year

Comment: @MikeT Rubish the dialog element is ideal for this. I have created dropdowns, PopUp's and Toasts with them. It is kind of their semantic purpose. They are new but are widely supported. READ the first paragraph on the link I provided from Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeed into creating the same component like Facebook or StackOverflow :

In the MainLayout.razor

```
  @inherits LayoutComponentBase
  <PageTitle>BlazorAuthServer</PageTitle>
<div class="page">
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<main>
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <LoginDisplay />
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark position-relative" @onclick="ToggleNotificationPopup" id="notificationButton">
            <i class="oi oi-bell" style="color: blue; block-size:stretch"></i> <!-- Icône de notification -->
            <span class="notification-badge position-absolute top-100 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
                @if(!ShowNotificationPopup){
                @NotificationCount <!-- Nombre de notifications -->
                }
            </span>
            @if (ShowNotificationPopup)
            {
                <div class="centered-div">
                    <NotificationPopup @bind-ShowPopup="@ShowNotificationPopup" />
                </div>
            }
        </button>
        
        <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <article class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </article>
</main>
</div>
  @code { 
private int NotificationCount = 3; // number of notifications

private bool ShowNotificationPopup { get; set; } = false;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    
}

private void ToggleNotificationPopup()
{
    // Toggle the visibility of the notification popup
    ShowNotificationPopup = !ShowNotificationPopup;
}

}
```

In the Component (that's the full code) :

```
    <!-- NotificationPopup.razor -->
@if (showPopup)
{
    <div class="floating-popup">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <!-- Your notification content here -->
            <p>Notification 1</p>
            <p>Notification 2</p>
            <p>Notification 1</p>
            <p>Notification 2</p>
            <p>Notification 1</p>
            <p>Notification 2</p>
            <p>Notification 1</p>
            <p>Notification 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool showPopup { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ShowPopupChanged { get; set; }
```

}

Finally the CSS:

```
.floating-popup {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 12rem;
    text-align: justify;
    color: red;
}

.floating-popup .popup-content {
max-height: 11rem; /* Set a maximum height for the content */
overflow-y: auto; /* Apply vertical scrollbar if needed */
max-width: 8rem;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.centered-div {
    position: absolute;
    top:3rem; /* Size of the Menu css top row*/
    left: -1rem;/*position X*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I now need to implement infinite scrolling. i'll keep you updted

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is the Blazor 8 implementation of my Notification service which consists of 4 files.

Enums.cs:

```
public enum BootstrapColor
{
    None,
    Danger,
    Info,
    Primary,
    Secondary,
    Success,
    Warning,
}

public enum NotificationPosition
{
    BottomLeft,
    Top,
    Center,
}
```

Notice.cs:

```
public class Notice
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string AlertCss { get; private set; }

    public string AlertShow { get; set; } = "show";

    public string IconCss { get; private set; }

    public DateTime RemoveAt { get; }

    public Notice(string message, BootstrapColor bootstrapColor, int removeAfterSeconds)
    {
        Message = message;
        RemoveAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(removeAfterSeconds);
        setCss(bootstrapColor);
    }

    void setCss(BootstrapColor bootstrapColor)
    {
        //" alert-dismissible fade show";

        switch (bootstrapColor)
        {
            case BootstrapColor.Danger:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-danger fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-exclamation-triangle";
                break;
            case BootstrapColor.Info:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-info fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-info-circle";
                break;
            case BootstrapColor.Primary:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-primary fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-info-circle";
                break;
            case BootstrapColor.Secondary:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-secondary fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-info-circle";
                break;
            case BootstrapColor.Success:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-success fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-check-circle";
                break;
            case BootstrapColor.Warning:
                AlertCss = "alert alert-warning fade";
                IconCss = "bi bi-exclamation-triangle";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationService.razor:

```
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@using System.Timers
@implements IDisposable

@if (notices != null)
{
    <div class="@positionCss">
        @foreach (var item in notices)
        {
            <div class="@item.AlertCss @item.AlertShow" style="max-width: 80vw; max-height: 80vh; overflow:hidden" role="alert">

                <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 justify-content-between">
                    <i class="@item.IconCss"></i>

                    <div style="max-width: 90%;">
                        @item.Message.ToMarkupString()
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button @onclick="() => close(item)" type="button" class="c-close-button" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="bi bi-x"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}


@code {
    List<Notice> notices; //Can't be a Queue because the user can arbitrarily close any notice if there are multiple notices being displayed
    string positionCss = ""; //use this to position danger messages in the center
    Timer timer;
    bool userClosing = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays a notice in the bottom left of the viewport.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlMessage">The message for the user. Can optionally be HTML. NOTE: If you include a link, be sure to add "alert-link" to the anchor class attribute for it to match Bootstrap's alert classes. For h1-h6 elements, use "alert-heading" <see href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/"></param>
    /// <param name="alertLevel">Determines the Bootstrap class to add to the alert. <see href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/" /> </param>
    /// <param name="removeAfterSeconds">How long the notice is displayed, in seconds. Default is 6</param>
    public void Notify(string htmlMessage = "Success", BootstrapColor alertLevel = BootstrapColor.Success, NotificationPosition position = NotificationPosition.Top, int removeAfterSeconds = 6)
    {
        notify(htmlMessage, alertLevel, position, removeAfterSeconds);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays a Bootstrap "alert-danger" notice in the center of the viewport
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlMessage">The message for the user. Can optionally be HTML. NOTE: If you include a link, be sure to add "alert-link" to the anchor class attribute for it to match Bootstrap's alert classes. For h1-h6 elements, use "alert-heading" <see href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/"></param>
    /// <param name="removeAfterSeconds">How long the notice is displayed, in seconds. Default is int.Max</param>
    public void NotifyError(string htmlMessage, int removeAfterSeconds = int.MaxValue)
    {
        notify(htmlMessage, BootstrapColor.Danger, NotificationPosition.Center, removeAfterSeconds);
    }

    public async Task NotifyNonSuccessResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, int removeAfterSeconds = int.MaxValue)
    {
        var msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var statusCode = response.StatusCode;

        string html = $"<h4 class='alert-heading'>{(int)statusCode} - {statusCode.ToString().ToTitleCase()}</h4><p class='mb-0'>{msg}</p>";

        notify(html, BootstrapColor.Danger, NotificationPosition.Center, removeAfterSeconds);
    }

    public void NotifyWithHeading(string heading, string htmlBody, BootstrapColor alertLevel = BootstrapColor.Info, NotificationPosition position = NotificationPosition.Top, int removeAfterSeconds = 15)
    {
        string html = $"<h4 class='alert-heading'>{heading}</h4><div>{htmlBody}</div>";
        notify(html, alertLevel, position, removeAfterSeconds);
    }

    #region Helpers

    async void close(Notice notice)
    {
        userClosing = true;
        notice.AlertShow = "";
        await Task.Delay(100); //give the fade CSS time to do it's thing
        notices.Remove(notice);
        userClosing = false;
    }

    void killTimer()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Elapsed -= timerElapsed;
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
        notices = null;
    }

    void notify(string htmlMessage, BootstrapColor bootstrapColor, NotificationPosition position, int removeAfterSeconds)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case NotificationPosition.BottomLeft:
                positionCss = "c-bottom-left-container";
                break;
            case NotificationPosition.Center:
                positionCss = "c-centered-container";
                break;
            case NotificationPosition.Top:
                positionCss = "c-top-container";
                break;
            default:
                positionCss = "c-bottom-left-container";
                break;
        }

        if (notices == null) notices = new();

        Notice notice = new(htmlMessage, bootstrapColor, removeAfterSeconds);
        notices.Add(notice);
        StateHasChanged();

        startTimerIfNotRunning();
    }

    void startTimerIfNotRunning()
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += timerElapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    async void timerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (userClosing) return;

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        bool stateHasChanged = false;
        for (int i = notices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (userClosing) return;
            var item = notices[i];
            if (item.RemoveAt <= now)
            {
                item.AlertShow = "";
                StateHasChanged(); //need this one for the fade effect
                await Task.Delay(100); //give the fade CSS time to do it's thing
                notices.Remove(item);
                stateHasChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if (notices.Count < 1)
        {
            killTimer();
            notices = null;
            stateHasChanged = true;
        }

        if (stateHasChanged) StateHasChanged(); //if an item has been removed or no items left
    }
    #endregion //helpers

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (timer != null) timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

NotificationService.razor.css:

```
.c-bottom-left-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.c-centered-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.c-top-container{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.c-close-button {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all .3s;
}

    .c-close-button:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: midnightblue;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
    }

.alert { /*Bootstrap's CSS is a bit much */
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
}
```

I also have a helper class, MarkupHelpers.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public static class MarkupHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders raw HTML into a view/page/component
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlString">The HTML string you want to render unescaped</param>
    /// <returns>Raw HTML</returns>
    public static MarkupString ToMarkupString(this string htmlString)
    {
        return new MarkupString(htmlString);
    }
}
```

which isn't necessary, but I'm not gonna rewrite my code right now.

To use it, ExamplePage.razor:

```
@page "/example-page"
<h3>ExamplePage</h3>

<NotificationService @ref="notificationService" />

@code {
    NotificationService notificationService;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        notificationService.Notify("Parameters set!");
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, if not, lemme know.